# Why does `'{x[1:3]}'.format(x="asd")` cause a TypeError?

Tags: python, typeerror, f-string

Consider this:

```
>>> '{x[1]}'.format(x="asd")
's'
>>> '{x[1:3]}'.format(x="asd")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

What could be the cause for this behavior?

Comment: Beautiful. This works with f-strings though: `x = 'asd' ; f'{x[1:3]}'`

Comment: If anything I'd have expected this to raise a syntax error as it breaks the [formatting mini-language rules](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) and not a type error.

Comment: @DeepSpace How does it break the rules?

Comment: @DeepSpace It doesn't break the rules, it's that the rules don't allow slicing.

Comment: @DeepSpace Similar: `i = 1; x = 'asd'; f'{x[i]'}` works very different than `'{x[i]}'.format(i=1, x='asd')`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

An experiment based on [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71787974/why-does-x13-formatx-asd-cause-a-typeerror/71788247?noredirect=1#comment126863009_71788247), checking what value the object's `__getitem__` method actually receives:

```
class C:
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        print(repr(index))

'{c[4]}'.format(c=C())
'{c[4:6]}'.format(c=C())
'{c[anything goes!@#$%^&]}'.format(c=C())
C()[4:6]
```

Output ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/PzknsbhYwdmKSwEIUlLTFOLj01NLMktSc@PjNYpTc9J0FDLzUlIrNCEqQKCgKDOvRKMotaBIAyKlycWlXp0cbRJbq66Xll@Um1iikWzrrAEUBwtbmWGXSMwDuiMzL10hPT@1WNFBWUU1Tg1TJZAAG/H/PwA)):

```
4
'4:6'
'anything goes!@#$%^&'
slice(4, 6, None)
```

So while the `4` gets converted to an `int`, the `4:6` isn't converted to `slice(4, 6, None)` as in usual slicing. Instead, it remains simply the *string* `'4:6'`. And that's not a valid type for indexing/slicing a string, hence the `TypeError: string indices must be integers` you got.

**Update:**

Is that documented? Well... I don't see something really clear, but @GACy20 [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71787974/why-does-x13-formatx-asd-cause-a-typeerror/71788247?noredirect=1#comment126874652_71788247) something subtle. The [grammar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) has these rules

```
field_name        ::=  arg_name ("." attribute_name | "[" element_index "]")*
element_index     ::=  digit+ | index_string
index_string      ::=  <any source character except "]"> +
```

Our `c[4:6]` is the `field_name`, and we're interested in the `element_index` part `4:6`. I think it would be clearer if `digit+` had its own rule with meaningful name:

```
field_name        ::=  arg_name ("." attribute_name | "[" element_index "]")*
element_index     ::=  index_integer | index_string
index_integer     ::=  digit+
index_string      ::=  <any source character except "]"> +
```

I'd say having `index_integer` and index_string would more clearly indicate that `digit+` is converted to an *integer* (instead of staying a digit string), while `<any source character except "]"> +` would stay a *string*.

That said, looking at the rules as they are, perhaps we should think *"what would be the point of separating the digits case out of the any-characters case which would match it as well?"* and think that the point is to treat pure digits differently, presumably to convert them to an integer. Or maybe some other part of the documentation even states that `digit` or `digits+` *in general* gets converted to an integer.

Comment: Philosophically, you could argue that it is the `index_string` case which is special here: `'{c[4]}'.format(c=c)` performs the same lookup as `c[4]` on its own; but `'{c[anything goes!@#$%^&]}'.format(c=c)` is acting as though there are quote marks inside the square brackets, i.e. `c['anything goes!@#$%^&']`. From that viewpoint, the slice syntax doesn't work because it's been pre-empted by the "implicit quote marks" case. (I stress that this is a philosophical argument, not a practical one.)

Answer (score 18):

`'{x[1]}'.format(x="asd")` the `[1]` syntax here is not the "normal" string indexing syntax, even if in this case it appears to be working the same way.

It is using the [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec). The same mechanism that allows for passing objects and accessing an arbitrary attribute inside the formatted string (eg `'{x.name}'.format(x=some_object)`).

This "fake" indexing syntax also allows to pass indexable objects to `format` and directly getting the element you want from within the formatted string:

```
'{x[0]}'.format(x=('a', 'tuple'))
# 'a'
'{x[1]}'.format(x=('a', 'tuple'))
# 'tuple'
```

The only reference (that I could find, at least) for this in the docs is this paragraph:

> The field_name itself begins with an arg_name that is either a number or a keyword. If it’s a number, it refers to a positional argument, and if it’s a keyword, it refers to a named keyword argument. If the numerical arg_names in a format string are 0, 1, 2, … in sequence, they can all be omitted (not just some) and the numbers 0, 1, 2, … will be automatically inserted in that order. Because arg_name is not quote-delimited, it is not possible to specify arbitrary dictionary keys (e.g., the strings '10' or ':-]') within a format string. The arg_name can be followed by any number of index or attribute expressions. An expression of the form '.name' selects the named attribute using getattr(), **while an expression of the form '[index]' does an index lookup using `__getitem__()`.**

While it mentions

> while an expression of the form '[index]' does an index lookup using `__getitem__()`.

it does not mention anything about slicing syntax not being supported.

For me this feels like an oversight in the docs, especially because `'{x[1:3]}'.format(x="asd")` generates such a cryptic error message, and even more so due to `__getitem__` already supporting slicing.

Comment: Interesting! I tried to see what's happening under the hood by running the following: `class C:^M def __getitem__(self, x):^M  print(repr(x))^Mf"{C()[1:2]}`

I got `slice(1, 2, None)`. I then tried `print("asd"[slice(1, 2, None))`, but it didn't result in TypeError. Am I misunderstanding what's happening?

Comment: Actually the grammar is pretty clear: `element_index     ::=  digit+ | index_string
index_string      ::=  <any source character except "]"> +` So the `element_index` is either a positive integer without leading `+` or "an index string": `"{x[1]} {x[+1]}".format(x={1: 'integer', '+1': 'string'}) -> 'integer string'`. In other words when using the `[index_element]` syntax `index_element` is always taken as a literal string **except** if it matches the regex `^\d+$` in which case it is interpreted as an integer. They could have included slicing syntax but they didn't

Comment: Note that even adding a space will break the int conversion: `"{x[ 1]}".format(x={' 1': 'string'}) -> 'string'`

Comment: @GACy20 I think you're right that that is meant that way, but I find it subtle. Included it in my answer now.